# MediaWiki 1.19.0 styles and skins not displaying

Tags: apache2, mediawiki

As the title of my question states I am having trouble with my MediaWiki 1.19.0.
I'm running apache2 and I have a few sites that are working fine. I downloaded and installed MediaWiki 1.19.0 and so far it works fine.
But if I try viewing my wiki page from another computer or over the internet the styles and skins don't display.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this problem while I had a similar one. My one could be fixed by upgrading from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

You need to yet yourself [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and find out  with it which styles/scripts HTTP requests are failing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem.  The load.php entry was not being created in the conf.d/mediawiki119.conf file.  It also wasn't creating the symlink from /var/www/mediawiki119/load.php to /user/share/mediawiki119/load.php.

Once you fix those two things it will work.

load.php was a new feature that loads the skins which is probably why they forgot it in some of the configuration files.